# MYSQL Migration toolkit error - The JRE library cannot be found

Tags: mysql

I am trying to migrate my data using MySql Migration ToolKit. I have installed it but it is showing me error indicating: Initialize Java Loader. When I check the path for my JRE library, it is correct in my environment variables but it is unable to read that path and say-

```
ERROR: The JRE library cannot be found at C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
Error Initializing Java modole loader(10014).
```

I ran the following command to make sure that my path is correct but still, it didnt work out:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Tools for 5.0>MySQLMigrationTool -verbose -jv
m "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll"
```

Can anyone help me out how to resolve this ?

Comment: you should try this, Go to Window - Preference - Java - Installed JREs page to specify the location of your jre or JDK.

Comment: @jmail, shouldn't it be the same as the one specified in my environment variables? I am able to run every other thing which requires java  but having issue only with Migration tool kit.